# chromium add a protocol handler

Tags: linux, man, chrome, info

A lot of years ago I was using kde/konqueror and one nice feature was the ability to open `man` and `info` pages using `man://` and `info://` as url protocol, I never checked but guess `man/info` pages were converted on the fly with some `man2html`.

Nowadays I'm using chromium (Debian/unstable) as primary browser, any way to get same feature?

**edit**

I logically thought about extensions (some link below) but found not much about handling custom protocols, injecting a javascript on a `file://` is trivial but most of `man` pages on my system are `gzipped`, the chrome extension framework seems to assume you're loading a valid file (page), found nothing about intercepting and run something before the url is loaded.

[Execute a program from a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19917672/2498790)

[Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101222/2498790)

[Convert all Linux man pages to text / html or markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13434016/2498790)

I'm now thinking about a `fuse` filesystem, should be relatively easy, plus would work with any browser.